# How to perform congregational (Jumah) prayer?

Tags: salat, jumuah

I am a recent revert to Islam and I wanted to begin reading Jumah Salah at my school.
I know how to read salah but I am not to sure about the stages of [Jumah](http://Jumah%20Salah) Salah.

Can someone please tell me how the process works and what I should do so I don't make a fool of myself at school when I go to pray with the others?

Comment: The answer here might be related:
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34863/how-to-read-the-5-salahs-in-the-mosque-behind-the-imam

Comment: Wasak wr wb...check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWOKB5EzHSo

Comment: @Ahmed i think he is asking about jamaa prayer

Comment: @goldPseudo isn't this dublicated ?

Comment: I think we need more information: What kind of help do you expect? Would it be sufficient if we explain it to you or do you need some pictures/videos and also maybe it could be interesting to know the sect as for example in a (Turkish) hanafi mosque most other sunnis might have a kind of culture shock!

Answer (score 0):

Walaikum salammm warahmatullahi wabarakatuh,

Jumah salah can not be done by alone. You have to attend the salah with other muslims in the masjid or wherever they pray jummah salah. It starts with a talk, khutba, and then finishes with 2 rakah fard salah with the imam. it takes about half an hour.